# Proof about factors of a composite number

Tags: number-theory

I'm wondering if there is a way to prove that every composite number, n, has a factor other than n, say $n_i$, such that $n_i \ge {\sqrt n}$, i.e. every composite number has a factor greater than its square root but less than the number itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n$ be a composite number. Then $n$ admits a decomposition $n = ab$, where $a,b > 1$. Both $a,b$ can't be less than$\sqrt{n}$, since otherwise $n = ab < n$. Therefore at least one of $a, b$ is $\geq \sqrt{n}$. Take that one to be $n_i$.